# React | Ant Design - Default value in Select component with Search with remote data

Tags: reactjs, antd

Using the below Example

https://ant.design/components/select/#components-select-demo-search-box

Scenario: Set Default value

Issue: Value getting loaded instead of the label

Query: How to set the default label along with the default value

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/form-in-modal-to-create-ant-design-demo-rvdnk

Answer (score 3):

check this out: https://codesandbox.io/s/search-box-ant-design-demo-g0pdh

Basically you need to set the value property on Option:

`<Option key={d.value} value={d.value}>`

Otherwise it won't know which option to choose.

Also, the value you set needs to be inside state.data (otherwise it won't find it and will not display it properly), so I added your initial value there:

```
  state = {
    data: [{ value: "喇叭袖上衣女", text: "123" }],
    value: "喇叭袖上衣女"
  };
```

Comment: My default values has to set from an async call, i have simulated the same in below by using a setTimeOut. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/form-in-modal-to-create-ant-design-demo-rvdnk

Comment: Not a problem, you just need to set `value` on `Select` and `value` on `Option` https://codesandbox.io/s/form-in-modal-to-create-ant-design-demo-hmsqc

Comment: Issue still exists,
https://codesandbox.io/s/form-in-modal-to-create-ant-design-demo-rvdnk

Comment: your link works just fine. Remember that you need to have the value inside your data array for it to show up properly inside the select. What doesn't work for you?

Comment: I think the issue is with useState, line 57, 58 confirms that.

Comment: Select shows value because it cannot find that value inside you data array

Comment: I think the issue is because of the use of props as default value in useState() directly.

Answer (score 1):

In case you already set value in the option like @tudor.gergely's comment. Make sure it has the same value, like in my case the default value was integer and the set value for option was string.

if default value was interger:

```
<Option key={d.value} value={d.value}>
```

if default value was string:

```
<Option key={d.value} value={`${d.value}`}>
```

In short, just make sure the initial value is the same as the option's value.